# How to get data from 3 diffrent tables in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a situation from which i have to get the data from three different tables and i want to use single query for that .How can we do this .Please help me .

Here in the situation:

```
 table_one

emp_id   dept_id      name
GT102    206          Test
GT103    201          Test1
GT105    111          Test2
GT106    340          Test3

table_two

Dept_id      department

111          Finance
340          Product
201          IT

table_three

emp_id      Salary

GT102       10,000
GT103       20,000
GT105       40,000
GT106       50,000
```

I want to fetch department and salary of Test2.Please help me

Comment: [click here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

Comment: i have seen this link but i am not getting the result .Please help me @Alexander

Comment: @user2901835 looking at it is not enough. You gotta read it and implement

Comment: @user2901835: Please add at your question a bit of your effort to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.name, 
       t2.department, 
       t3.salary 
FROM   table_one t1
       INNER JOIN table_two t2
              ON t2.dept_id = t1.dept_id 
       INNER JOIN table_three t3
              ON t1.emp_id = t3.emp_id 
WHERE  t1.name = 'Test2'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Select table_two.department, table_three.Salary From table_one, table_two, table_three where table_one.emp_id = table_three.emp_id and table_one.dept_id = table_two.Dept_id and table_one.name='Test2'
```

Answer (score 0):

`select table_two.department,table_three.Salary from table_one join table_two on table_one.dept_id=table_two.dept_id join table_three on table_three.emp_id= table_one.emp_id WHERE table_one.name like 'Test2';`